# Regular Expression describing language accepted by Finite State Automata

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-expressions

[image: Finite State Automata]

Hopefully I am including the image correctly or this won't make any sense.  I am trying to figure out a regular expression for what this FSA accepts.  From what I can tell it accepts any combination of 01 or 10 repeated.  Wouldn't the expression then be ((01)* | (10)*) *

I believe I have what it should be as correct I just don't know if I am representing that answer as a regular expression in the correct form.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It does not seem correct to me. Why do you have the last star?

Comment: where is the accept state?

Comment: `((01)* | (10)*)*` can be written simpler `((01)|(10))*`

Comment: The accepting state is q0.  For that last star doesnt it have to be there because it could be the expression can alternate back and forth from 10 to 01.  ie 10011001 or 01100110

Comment: @rain1: The double circle is a conventional notation for an acceptor state.

Comment: It is confusing then that the q3 state is listed in this diagram and cannot be escaped from.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is correct, though I, like **rain1**, would simplify it to $(01\mid 10)^*$: if you let $u=01$ and $v=10$, the automaton accepts any string over the alphabet $\{u,v\}$.